FastEndpoints PATCH with route param, headers and no body
What im trying to do is send a PATCH call to an endpoint which has route params but also required headers and no body.
public class TestRequest
{
    [FromHeader("x-correlation-id")]
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    [BindFrom("EntityId")]
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TestEndpoint : Endpoint<TestRequest>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Patch("{EntityId}/fulfill");
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(TestRequest req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await SendOkAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

The above displays the 2 properties in Swagger UI but when i call it i get 415 Unsupported Media Type which as i understand is returned because the FastEndpoints Endpoint<T> sends a body even though its empty. I can verify this if i manually send the properties as the route param and header accordingly and set the Content-type: application/json header which in turn returns a JsonSerializer error because the body is null and not in a json format.
I have also tried with EndpointWithoutRequest but this does not take any model as a request therefore the CorrelationId prop cannot be set and i cannot find any way to set it in the endpoint.
What i would like to find is a way to display all the header properties and the route params in SwaggerUi and be able to send a simple curl with
curl -X 'PATCH' \
  '.../72423509-c29b-4735-862a-9ebdd0489c05/fulfill' \
  -H 'x-correlation-id: 72423509-c29b-4735-862a-9ebdd0489c05'


seems like as is, you are sending a GET.  Why not send params in body?  All non-GET verbs are basically same as POST.  Seems like should also be "fulfill/your_param", and you could route fullfill to a controller/method.  (not familiar with FastEndpoints, though...)

in general you should avoid doing any state-changing through a GET.  That way you don't have to remember to always check for the custom header value.  It's just better to separate those concerns so that you can know that a GET never changes state.  (CSRF concern... those URLs are often exposed in logs as well)

Where did you come up that i'm sending a GET request? The endpoint is clearly marked as a PATCH. The issue that i believe that im facing is that the PATCH is sending an empty body because of the Endpoint<TestRequest> but without a content type

you have parameters in the URL, no?  That's a GET-like query.  All other verbs are basically POST, where parameters are expected in the body.  It's just better to treat all GETs = non-sensitive parameters in URL so that you separate the security concerns.  (csrf, logging, verb tampering)  If mixing URL parameters with non-GETs just be aware of various possible exploits and security concerns.

The answer was given by the creator of FE. https://github.com/FastEndpoints/FastEndpoints/issues/492#issuecomment-1740210893
public override void Configure()
{
    Put("/settings/{Id}/toggle");
    Description(x => x.Accepts<ToggleSettingRequest>());
}


AllowAnonymous looks a little dangerous for a patch, no?  This is also for a different endpoint with different parameters.  What did your specific fix end up being?
